# Sum function for unformat text cells to have finally size in gb

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum and have finally size in gigabytes (gb) this unformat text cells in excel without passing through formatting text before.

```
810.9MB
1.2GB
395.1MB
982.3MB
7.7GB
149.4MB
10.0GB
429.1MB
3.1GB
```

Problem is that I have 2 units, MB and GB. Both units are numbers 'attach' so I can't have finally size correctly [24.76 gb]

I expect this:

```
810.9MB
1.2GB

Σ (summarization)

2.01 GB
```

but in excel I have list only so I can't use Sigma sign Σ

Comment: Are you expecting a marketer's results using 10⁶ and 10⁹ or true Mb and Gb as in 2²⁰ and 2³⁰?

Comment: I expect this: 810.9MB + 1.2GB = 2.0109 GB but in excel I have list only so I can't use Sigma sign Σ

Comment: Then you are using 10-based Mbs and Gbs, not 2-based Mbs and Gbs. See the footnotes in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want a difference of 10³ between a Mb¹ and a Gb¹, use the following array formula² to total up your sample figures.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10, IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MB", A2:A10)), "MB", "GB"), ""),
            IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MB", A2:A10)), POWER(10, -3), 1))
```

Finish off with a custom number format of `0.0#\G\B` to retain a true number while displaying a GB increment. Note that in the sample image the sum is right-aligned as a true number should be while the individual figures as left-aligned (as text defaults to).

[image: SUM GB MB]

The [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) typically provides a layer of cyclic (aka *array*²) processing without CSE but the in-line IF functions require CSE to provide an extra level of array processing.

---

¹ <sub>A megabyte is actually 2²⁰, not 10⁶. A gigabyte is 2³⁰, not 10⁹.</sub>

² <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: I select cells A2 through A10, and then enter your formula. Then I press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER but it return me an error. It mark **A10,**. What is the problem?

Comment: Your data does not match the sample data you provided. As you can see in the image, it works on the data you provided. What is the error?

Comment: Solved.. I used an Italian Excel Version so.. it gave me an error. Now is all ok! Excellent!